# Iterations through a set of n variables

Tags: java, loops, optimization, structure

I want to create a data structure (or use an existing one) to iterate easily through all possible
elements in form of: **(i<sub>1</sub>, i<sub>2</sub>, ..., i<sub>n</sub>)** such that
**i<sub>j</sub>** belongs to **[i<sub>j_lower</sub>, i<sub>j_upper</sub>]**. Those are all integer values. I iterate this way:

```
for (int i1 = i1_lower; i1 <= i1_upper; i1++) {
        for (int i2 = i2_lower; i2 <= i2_upper; i2++) {
            for (int i3 = i3_lower; i3 <= i3_upper; i3++) {
                /*
                 * 
                 */
                for (int in = in_lower; in <= in_upper; i++) {

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It may not be a good solution for large n. How to make it easier?

Comment: Not clear what you're trying to achieve. Provide a limited source data and the desired result.

Comment: It is purely **theoretical**, it can be used for example to generate all words with the length of n... where ij is the ASCII code of the j-th letter.

Comment: Are you talking about permutation groups?

Comment: Not really. For example: for n = 2, i1 from 1 to 3, i2 from 1 to 2...
I wanna do sth for:
i1 = 1, i2 = 1 and then
i1 = 1, i2 = 2 and then
i1 = 2, i2 = 1 and then
i1 = 2, i2 = 2 and then
i1 = 3, i2 = 1 and then
i1 = 3, i2 = 2.

Comment: OK. I go back to my previous request for sample data and the associated result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no point in making it easier, as it is not practical.